# centos 7 подключение по SSH по моему айпи

Tags: сеть, centos7

я довольно таки новичек в данной теме, но интересно узнать.

Каким образом другие пользователи могут подключаться к Centos7 по SSH по моему айпи (выданому провайдером).

Локальный сервер настроен и я сам без труда могу подключиться по SSH.

Может есть какие-то статьи которые могли бы посоветовать, ибо в google нахожу не то что надо.

Прописывая в настройках интерфейса IP, MASK, GATEWAY и DNS провайдера, все равно не удается войти по IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле все очень просто, но есть несколько моментов:
1. Какой ip адрес вам выдал провайдер? (белый динамический, белый статический, или серый)
если белый статический, то это самый простой вариант, просто необходимо на вашем роутере пробросить порт ssh (по умолчанию 22 порт) на ip вашего сервера.
Если IP адрес белый динамический, то можно использовать любой сервис ddns., и также настроить проброс порта
Если серый ip адрес, то вариант только с поднятием VPN...но это уже другая история
2. Уточнить у провайдера, включен ли по дефолту NAT, например у домру, по умолчанию включен, можно отключить в личном кабинете.
В дополнение к своему ответу приложу несколько полезных ссылок для ознакомления
[Тыц1](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5c17239287f1e000ac197cf7/kak-sdelat-svoi-server-iz-domashnego-pk-5c20619acaa0bf00a994b9d7)
[Тыц2](https://hackware.ru/?p=4780)

Comment: Помог первый способ, с пробросом портов SSH.

Большое Вам спасибо :)